# What is the deleted folder name link for Outlook?

Tags: java, email, outlook, jakarta-mail

I have a code snippet for deleting emails from Gmail. But I need to change that line `store.getFolder("[Gmail]/Trash");` to work with the Outlook server.
What is the deleted(trash) folder name link for Outlook?

```
store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect("imap.gmail.com",<username>,<password>);
inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
deletedMessages.add(message);
message.setFlag(Flag.SEEN,true);
if (inbox.isOpen()) {
    if(deletedMessages.size() > 0){
        trash = store.getFolder("[Gmail]/Trash");
        Message[] tempMessageArray = deletedMessages.toArray(new Messag                    e[deletedMessages.size()]);
        inbox.copyMessages(tempMessageArray,trash);
        deletedMessages.clear();
 }
 inbox.close(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Outlook,  there are two options:

[image: Outlook menu bar]

So you could use `[Outlook]/Deleted Items` or `[Outlook]/Junk Email`. Probably most comparable to `[Gmail]/Trash` is `[Outlook]/Deleted Items`. `Junk Email` catches additional Spam email not blocked by Outlooks filters.

For more info, see : [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/working-with-message-folders-in-outlook-com-6bb0723a-f39f-4a8d-bb3f-fab5dcc2510a#:~:text=In%20the%20folder%20pane%2C%20right%2Dclick%20the%20folder%20you%20want,the%20folder%20and%20press%20Enter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/working-with-message-folders-in-outlook-com-6bb0723a-f39f-4a8d-bb3f-fab5dcc2510a#:%7E:text=In%20the%20folder%20pane%2C%20right%2Dclick%20the%20folder%20you%20want,the%20folder%20and%20press%20Enter).